# Error Message : ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Tags: oracle

I'am trying to try this sql command for oracle in toad program but it doesn't work, Although its work in MySQL:phpMyAdmin

so what the right way to write this command:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE CONCAT ('first_name' , 'last_name'  , 'phone') LIKE '%00%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONCAT` in Oracle DB can only handle 2 Parameter. You can use nested `concat`statements:

```
 CONCAT ('first_name' , CONCAT ('last_name'  , 'phone'))
```

or the concat operator `||`

```
'first_name' || 'last_name' || 'phone'
```

Comment: Thnak you so much

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, the CONCAT function only accepts 2 arguments. But you can nest CONCAT calls:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(last_name, '''s job category is '),
  job_id) "Job" 
FROM employees 
WHERE employee_id = 152;
Job
------------------------------------------------------
Hall's job category is SA_REP
```

For more information, check oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm